# define a global variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use a variable outside my foreach. how can I solve that in PHP. How can I use $ID outside the foreach?

```
foreach($row as $key => $value) {
  $ID = $value['Id'];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just try it? You're assuming a behavior for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ID = null;
foreach($row as $key => $value) {
  $ID = $value['Id'];
}
//do something with $ID...
```

The reason for this is that if the for loop is never gone through (that is, $row was an empty array) $ID would never be set. Therefore, `$ID` has to be set beforehand or else it won't be in scope at all and if you try to access `$ID`'s value, you will hit errors.

Comment: what is misleading? if the for loop is never gone thru (aka `$row` was of 0 length) $ID would never be set.

Comment: There is no need to define `$ID` outside of the foreach structure.

Comment: see my edited comment above. it is ness just in case the foreach loop is NOT run

Comment: While good practice, it is misleading because it has nothing to do with the fact that if the question is "how can I access that variable outside the loop?" the answer is "you can access it without doing anything else".

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel. read my explanation in the comments. or ill just add it to my answer...

Answer (score 5):

Your `$ID` variable can already be used outside of your `foreach` : a control structure doesn't come with its own [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

As a quick illustration, the following portion of code :

```
$ID = 0;

$array = array(1, 2, 3);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $ID = $value;
}

var_dump($ID);
```

Will get you :

```
int 3
```

Which shows that the `$I`D variable that's used inside the `foreach` loop is the same as the one that exists outside that loop.

---

**Edit after the comments :**

Not initializing the variable before the loop, you'd get exactly the same result : the variable would be created the first time it used -- and it would in the same scope as in the example I posted.

Another example, now, using a function inside the `foreach` loop *(only works with PHP >= 5.3)* :

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $func = function () use ($value) {
        $ID = $value;
        var_dump($ID);
    };
    $func();
}

var_dump($ID);
```

There, the `$ID` variable is not initialized before the loop -- it's created in the function that's inside the loop.

This example would get the following output :

```
int 1
int 2
int 3

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: ID ... on line 15

null
```

Basically :

- You get three correct output, from inside the function

  - Those show the `$ID` variable, inside the anonymous function, is getting a value
- But, after the loop, you get a notice : the `$ID` variable doesn't exist.

  - Which show that the `$ID` variable created inside the function is not the same as the `$ID` variable outside the function : the function comes with its own variable scope.

Comment: True but it's always good to initialize variables outside of such control structures

Comment: @Cfreak : I tend to agree -- and I've edited my answer with an example, in the meantime.

Comment: The example doesn't exactly demonstrate that control structures don't create a scope, it seems that it works because you defined `$ID` before. That would work - for example - in Perl even with a function instead of the foreach, but wouldn't work if you didn't define the variable in the outer scope (because they do create a scope).

Answer (score 1):

You can use it outside your `foreach`, variables scopes are not limited by statement structure.

On the other hand, they are limited by functions scope.

See this page from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for more informations about variables scope.

Answer (score 0):

Having a variable inside a foreach loop does affect it's scope.  You are free to manipulate that variable before, after or in the foreach loop to your desires.

Answer (score 0):

there is not much sense in assigning all values to single variable in turn.
if you want only last one, it can be substituted with

```
$value = array_pop($row);
$ID = $value['Id'];
```

but I doubt it's what you really need. what is whole task you're trying to solve? 
May be you want an array?

```
$id_arr = array();
foreach($row as $key => $value) {
  $id_arr[] = $value['Id'];
}
```